# Restricting Source IP of DDNS Updates

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, dns-zone, dynamic-dns

Goal:
For a non-Microsoft DHCP server to send dynamic DNS updates on behalf of non-Microsoft domain clients.

Question:
With a particular zone in a Microsoft DNS server configured for "Nonsecure and secure" updates, **can Microsoft limit which IP addresses are allowed to send dynamic DNS updates to the entire server or zone?**

We would like to limit only the the non-MS DHCP server to send updates Microsfot and would like to achieve this goal in this fashion.

GSS-TSIG is another option that does work; although, I need to explore this option due to some limitations of the Kerberos protocol.

Environment:

1 Non-Microsoft DHCP server

1 MS DNS server

I have been looking into this for some time and have come across the following articles:

[How to limit dynamic DNS updates](https://serverfault.com/questions/645311/how-to-limit-dynamic-dns-updates)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649193%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: IP address ACLs should not be mixed with DNS when there are security implications. UDP is stateless and easily spoofed. Unless you're using a key to authenticate the DDNS changes, this is completely insecure.

Comment: @AndrewB Thank you Andrew for the quick response. Point taken.

Comment: Considering the risks, would the DNS ACL's that allows only specify source IP's to accept dynamic DNS updates be applied in Windows Firewall or somewhere in the DNS configuration? I cannot find a configuration window within MS' DNS Management. Thank you.

Comment: Firewalling will not prevent a spoofed source IP, unfortunately. You would have to firewall UDP off completely and only allow TCP. TCP includes a session handshake, UDP does not. The latter can be used to spoof DDNS updates unless the packets contain a signature. Beyond that, I'm not a Windows expert and I will defer to someone else. :)